# Missing iframe ie8. Relative positioning doesn't resolve issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I am implementing a 3rd party 2fa solution (Duo Web) on a site using their PHP and Javascript.
I have it working on all browsers but IE8.
After passing the initial login screen the 2fa login page loads and the iframe that should have the 2fa prompt is blank.

After reading some threads here is seems the normal solution for iframes in ie8 is to either remove position relative from the embedded page or give it to the iframe.
Since I don't have access to the page I added relative positioning to the frame to no effect.  Here is the weird part, this only occurs on your first visit to the 2fa page.

Reloading the page displays the iframe correctly.  The code also seems to be present.  There is an option in Duo to have a login request automatically sent on arriving at the 2fa page.  When this is enabled the request appears in the Duo app and you can correctly log in even when the iframe is blank.

So it appears the code works, the iframe is just blank.  Again, this only occurs on the first visit to the page.  After that the iframe correctly displays until the browser is closed and reopened.

I cannot show the exact code due to this being work related but it's basically

```
<div id="iframe_container" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
    <iframe id="duo_iframe" frameborder="0">Loading...</iframe>
    // this form passes data along when response comes back
    <form method="POST" id="duo_form"> 
        <input type="hidden"/>
        <input type="checkbox"/><label for="checkbox"><small>Remember this device</small></label>
    </form>
    // form to log user out and send them back to normal login page
    <form method="GET" action="url">
        <input type="hidden" />
        <input type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Go Back">
    </form>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows

```
#duo_iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 304px;
    max-width: 620px;
    height: 330px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I am running in compatibility mode, but disabling it does not resolve the issue.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a race condition.  When first loading the embedded page it's initialization Javascript was firing before the elements were available.  When refreshing the main page the embedded content is cached so it loads before the js fired.  Adding a timeout that recalls the init function after a few seconds fixes the issue.